# Given a number and two lists whose values at each index correspond, how to decode an iteger?

Tags: python, list, math, decoding

The problem I am facing is with my decoder function. To my knowledge, I encode the value properly; however, it is not decoding back to the given string. I provided an example of the encoding process and equation used within encoder() block.

As you will be able to see from the code I provided, I tried to used val % 4, to get the remainder, and then deducted 1 to get the index; however, the string that is being returned is not the same string I encoded.

This is the current state of my program:

```
import numpy as np

alphabet = {
        'a': 1,
        'b': 2,
        'c': 3,
        'd': 4
    }

def encoder(val):
    """
    Params:
        val(string): string that we are going to encode must be length 5 or less
    Alphabet and corresponding values:
        alphabet: {a b c d}
        values: {1 2 3 4} -> for encoding
    Returns:
        econded_value(int)
    """

    # example: babca
    # encoded: (2 x (4^4)) + (1 x (4^3)) + (2 x (4^2)) + (3 x (4^1)) + (1 x (4^0))

    encoded_val = 0
    power = len(val) - 1 # keeps track of what value we need to put 4 to the power of

    # to encode we need to loop over the string
    for i in range(len(val)):
        encoded_val += ((4**power) * alphabet[val[i]])
        power -= 1

    return encoded_val


def decoder(val):
    r_string = ""

    # convert dictionary to two lists so we can access the keys (letters) using the values (numbers) thus making the decoded string
    letter_list = list(alphabet.keys())
    number_list = list(alphabet.values())

    print(letter_list, number_list)

    while val > 0:
        r_string += letter_list[number_list[(val%4)-1]]
        val = val // 4

    return r_string


if __name__ == '__main__':

    val = encoder("babca")

    print(decoder(val))
```

Comment: `val%4` is going to produce a value of 0, 1, 2, or 3; subtracting 1 from that turns the range to -1, 0, 1 or 2.  Is that really what you want?  *Adding* 1 seems more likely to work here.

Comment: @jasonharper `(val%4)-1` is used as indices for the values of the alphabet. E.g. `0` maps to `1` which maps to `'a'`. A little convoluted, but that's not the error.

Comment: Having 1 through 4 as the values of the alphabet, then using %4 to decode, is going to be problematic. Think about decimal numbers. We can successively do n%10 to get the individual digits, but our digits are 0 through 9, not 1 through 10.

Comment: The big issue I see is in the length of the code. Since you encode 4 letters using 1-4, 4 being `0b100` and `4^n` shifts only 2 for every increment of `n`, you'll start overwriting previously written codeletters once you want to write d.

Answer (score 0):

Though the problem I mentioned in my comment is still present, the issue is in this piece of code:

```py
letter_list = list(alphabet.keys())
number_list = list(alphabet.values())
```

Since your dictionary maps 'a' to 1, 'b' to 2 etc. you expect the same to hold for the lists. However, the letterlist maps index 0 to 'a', 1 to 'b' etc.

To fix this (in the quickest but ugliest way), you need to subtract one from the index here:

```py
r_string += letter_list[number_list[(val%4)-1]-1]
```

Instead of indexing like that, you can loop through the dictionary:

```py
r_string += [l for l, i in alphabet.items() if i == val%4][0]
```

However, the string is in reverse, so don't forget to reverse it back:

```py
return r_string[::-1]
```

Which gives the following output string:

```py
babca
```

---

Personally, I would use a base that is calculated on runtime to see how many bits are required to encode the message. If the longest encoded character takes N bits, we bitshift by N when encoding/decoding:

```py
import numpy as np

alphabet = {
        'a': 1,
        'b': 2,
        'c': 3,
        'd': 4
    }

def encoder(val, base):
    """
    Params:
        val(string): string that we are going to encode
        base(int): number of bits per encoded letter
    Alphabet and corresponding values:
        alphabet: {a b c d}
        values: {1 2 3 4} -> for encoding
    Returns:
        encoded_value(int)
    """

    encoded_val = 0

    # to encode we need to loop over the string
    for i in val:
        # e.g. we encoded 0b101 and we add 110, we get encoded_val = 0b101110
        encoded_val = (encoded_val << base) | alphabet[i]

    return encoded_val


def decoder(val, base):
    r_string = ""

    while val > 0:
        # e.g. base = 3, val = 0b101110, we get 110 by doing 0b101110 & 0b111
        r_string += [l for l, i in alphabet.items() if i == val & (1 << base) - 1][0]
        # 0b101110 >> 3 = 0b101
        val = val >> base

    return r_string[::-1]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    base = max(alphabet.values()).bit_length()   # to get number of bits to shift by largest encoded value
    # base = len(alphabet).bit_length()       -->  if all values are sequential as 1-N
    val = encoder("dcbabcd", base)

    print(decoder(val, base))
```

Output:

```py
dcbabcd
```

This also fixes the issue of 'd' writing over the previously encoded letters.

Comment: This works assuming there is no 'd' in the string. But if the string has a 'd', we run into the problem you mentioned in your comment of using 4 as a 'digit' in a base-4 encoding.